# Different notions of computable binary sequence

Tags: computability-theory, infinite-sequences

The standard definition of computability, for a sequence $s\in\{0,1\}^\omega$, is that there is a Turing machine outputting $s[i]$ on input $i$.

I'm looking for strengthenings of this notion; for example, in the above definition it's not decidable whether there is a $1$ in $s$; or, given $i$, whether there is a $1$ in $s$ at position $\ge i$. I would be happy to be shown a "natural" definition of computability that makes these predicates computable.

To the above: if there were an algorithm that, from the Turing machine producing $s$, tells us whether $s$ contains a $1$ then I could do the following: from any Turing machine $M$, program a Turing machine outputting $s[i]=1$ if $M$ stops after $\le i$ steps. This sequence $s$ is obviously computable --- I said how to compute it --- but an algorithm determining if the sequence contains a $1$ would solve the Halting problem.

A search through the literature didn't show anything, so links and references are most welcome!

Comment: Can you say more about what you mean by "strengthening"? It's a very broad question. If we view $s$ as a subset of all strings on a finite alphabet, where $s[i] = 1$ if and only if the $i$th string is in the language, then all of formal languages are relevant, e.g. regular, context-free, etc.

Comment: Yes, you're right that my question is imprecise. I was hoping that there was a large class of Turing machines for which, at least, the above predicates are decidable -- something much larger than rational. @usul, we might write $i$ in unary, and view $s\subset\{0\}^*$, or in binary, and view $s\subset\{0,1\}^*$, the answers will definitely be different but both interest me!

Comment: when you say "it's not decidable whether there is a 1 in $s$", I'm not sure what you mean. If you have in mind that the input is $s$ (an arbitrary element of $\{0,1\}^\omega$), this is not a possible input for a Turing machine: you can input an integer or an equivalent datum, e.g. a finite sequence. When you say "whether there is a 1 in $s$ at position $\ge i$", again the input can't be $s$, but let's say that the input is $i$. Then you get the characteristic function of an initial segment of $\omega$, and this is obviously a computable function.

Comment: @YCor The input to that decision problem is obviously the sequence $s$. We can view this in two ways: The Polish style, where the sequence is written out on the input tape, or the Russian style, where the sequence is given by the code of a Turing machine that would write it. For natural problems, it usually makes no difference regarding decidability of questions, and this applies here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What a *computable sequence* is essentially follows from what computability is, and from what a sequence is.

Let us first agree that a sequence over $\mathbf{X}$ is a function $s : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbf{X}$. Then asking that whether or not a sequence over $\{0,1\}$ is constant be decidable amounts to

1. Solving the Halting problem for whatever notion of computability we work with (as explained in the question)
2. Demanding that $\mathbb{N}$ is compact (in the sense of synthetic topology)

This tells us that any notion of computability with this property is extremely weird, and probably should not be considered a notion of computability at all.

Of course, we could use a mixed view, where we use a restricted version of computability on the sequence, and a more powerful one to decide whether its constant. In that case, we just need that the second notion can decide the Halting problem for the first.

Alternatively, we could replace $\{0,1\}^\omega$ by something different, but similar. We can view this as $\mathcal{P}(\omega)$, but all standard notions of computability on this are weaker than $\{0,1\}^\omega$. Using Joseph Miller's $\Pi$-topology on $\{0,1\}^\omega$, we could get that whether sequence is constant becomes decidable. Unfortunately, there are no computable points in the $\Pi$-topology at all.

We could brute-force it, say by tagging any $p \in \{0,1\}^\omega$ by the cardinality of $|\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid p(n) = 1\}|$, but I fail to see how this would be interesting.

Answer (score 7):

You can look at [automatic structures](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~minnes/LCsurvey.pdf), replacing Turing machines by finite automata. In that setting, the whole first order theory is decidable (in particular you can add existential quantifiers like you describe), by a Theorem of Hodgson.

*Hodgson, Bernard R.*, [**On direct products of automaton decidable theories**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0304-3975(82)90042-1), Theor. Comput. Sci. 19, 331-335 (1982). [ZBL0493.03002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0493.03002).

Comment: Thanks!
(see my comment above) It also seems to depend heavily on the way in which we encode the index $i$. I see now that there's the notion of k-automatic sequence (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_sequence), is this the same as what you have in mind?

Comment: Yes, I guess I mean 2-automatic